# How to change cloud foundry web socket load balancing port 4443

Tags: websocket, cloud-foundry

Default cloud foundry web socket load balancing port is 4443, is it possible to change it to 443 ?

Can it be configured at container level?

Answer (score 1):

As an end user, no.  It's entirely up to your platform administrator and how they configure the platform.

In most cases, there is a reason why WebSocket connections are done over 4443 and not 443.  It's not a requirement of CloudFoundry, rather it's usually because the load balancer being used in front of CloudFoundry doesn't support doing both HTTP/HTTPD & WebSockets.  To work around this, you have to use two load balancers, one listening on 80/443 & one listening on 4443 (or some other port).  The biggest culprit of this is AWS & Elastic Load Balancers.